# How I minify two related js

Tags: javascript, minify

I have two javascript

- ol.js minify version 400kb
- ol-debug.js original version 3000kb
- app.js my script using ol functions.

For development I need to use ol-debug.js so I can use the real name properties and functions.

So how I can develop my app.js using the debug version and then minify both?

For example when I use `Jquery` or `Jquery-min` dont have that problem, the function name doesnt get minify. So what is different here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to take several source JavaScript files (not minified) and minify all of them into a single minified file.

You need a minifier - software that takes your JavaScript files, minify and combines them into a single minified file.

One example is:
https://github.com/mrclay/minify

I hope it helps a bit!